# How can I check variable is defined or not in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I want a if condition in ColdFusion which is check `#firstWordCategory#` variable is defined or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every variable will be in some scope and scope(mostly) is simply a structure.

So, you can use [`structKeyExists()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structkeyexists.html) like this:

```
<!--- If your variable is in VARIABLES scope --->
<cfif structKeyExists(VARIABLES, "firstWordCategory")>

    <!--- Your Code --->

</cfif>
```

Comment: This won't work if you have local variable defined. For example `<cfset var myVar = "Test">`. I had to use `isDefined("myVar")` instead.

Comment: @espresso_coffee That will also create a variable in LOCAL scope for CF9+ so `structKeyExists( LOCAL, "myVar" )` will work.

Comment: I didn't know about LOCAL scope. Your answer will work for global variables but not for local. Thank you.

Comment: OP didn't specify the scope so its been assumed to be in `VARIABLES` scope as stated in comments: `<!--- If your variable is in VARIABLES scope --->`.

Try this:
`<cfoutput>IsDefined "myVar1": #test1()#<br> StructKeyExists "myVar2": #test2()#</cfoutput><cffunction name="test1"><cfset var myVar1 = ""><cfreturn isDefined( "myVar1" )></cffunction><cffunction name="test2"><cfset LOCAL.myVar2 = ""><cfreturn structKeyExists( LOCAL, "myVar2" )></cffunction>`

Comment: I just tested it using the following:
<cffunction name="varsTest" output="false" access="public" returntype="any" hint="varsTest">
 <cfset var results = "set in local scope."/>
 <cfif structKeyExists(local,"results")>
  <cfset request.cfdumpinited = false />
  <cfdump label="local" expand="true" var="#local#" abort="true" />
  <cfreturn results />
 <cfelse>
  <cfreturn "Nothing There" />
 </cfif>
</cffunction>

the results variable is definitely in the local scope in this case.

Answer (score 6):

To check any variable existence you can use `isDefined` function:

```
<cfif isDefined("firstWordCategory")>
    <cfoutput>#firstWordCategory#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

For more check [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7fe0.html).